# virt-manager not working on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I've installed KVM/QEMU/libvirt on my laptop and am trying to access it using virt-manager.  When I run `sudo virt-manager -c qemu:///system` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 399, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 256, in main
    from virtManager import cli
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/cli.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libvirt
ImportError: No module named libvirt
```

I've tried changing the PYTHONPATH and reinstalling virt-manager with no luck.  I've been able to succesfully install virt-manager on an ubuntu vm in esxi to manage another KVM host, and am following the same process.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Which Python version is the default on your laptop?

Comment: `Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar 25 2015, 13:38:54) 
92-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 [542 kB]                                                       │[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2`

Comment: That should work with it. The libvirt module is in package `python-libvirt`, is that package installed? Is there file `/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libvirtmod.so` on your system and does `ldd /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libvirtmod.so` find all required libraries?

Comment: `python-libvirt` is installed but I don't appear to have the `libvirtmod.so` file: ```willem  ~  sudo apt-get install python-libvirt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-libvirt is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
 willem  ~  
 willem  ~  ls /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/ | grep libvirtmod.so
 willem  ~  ldd /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libvirtmod.so
ldd: /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libvirtmod.so: No such file or directory```

Comment: If you are really running Ubuntu 12.04 then the package is corrupted in the system (someone deleted the file? filesystem corruption?). According to file list of [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-libvirt), the file is installed with the package. You can reinstall the package to get it back but there may be some other issues with the system. You can also check with `dpkg -L python-libvirt` if the file was installed with this package.

Comment: it appears I have the file here: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirtmod.so`  following a suggested link ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/587226 ) could this be my problem? `willem  ~  which python
/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Do you really have Ubuntu 12.04? The file was moved in newer Ubuntus. If you have local version of Python, that could be the problem as well.

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python python-old #example name
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

[how do I update PYTHONPATH from /usr/local/bin/python to /usr/bin/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970027/how-do-i-update-pythonpath-from-usr-local-bin-python-to-usr-bin-python/29970431#29970431)