# how do I update PYTHONPATH from /usr/local/bin/python to /usr/bin/python

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I am unable to use virt-manager, and I think it's because of where my python is located.  When I run the `virt-manager` command I get: `No module named libvirt` even though I have libvirt installed.  When I run `/usr/bin/python /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py` it works fine.  The output from `which python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`.  I've tried creating a `~/.bash_profile` that contains this: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/bin/python` but am still having the same problem.
I'm sure there is a simple solution to this?

Comment: if you check `echo $PYTHONPATH`, do you see the updated path? if not, you have to either reopen your current terminal to see the changes, or to make them avaiable in the current session run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Did you `source` the .bash_profile after editing it ?

Comment: no, where do I source it, in my .bashrc?

Comment: @RMPhoenix, just run this in any directory: `source ~/.bash_profile`. And it should update your environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a symbolic link, example:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python python-old # example name
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the PYTHONPATH environmental variable sets where your python session looks for modules. It doesn't set the location of your python interpreter, which I think is what you want to do.

What you need to do is add and alias for the python interpreter that you do want to use to your bash_profile. Something like this:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python'
```